# Create property with same name as type

Tags: swift2

I tried doing this in a class declaration.

```
public var Thing : Thing = Thing()
```

It says,

> Variable used within its own initial value

If I remove the assignment then it gives.

> Thing used within its own type

So no luck. Is it possible to use the same name for the property as the type? Its possible in C# :) At present I have lower cased the property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you conform to the naming convention and declare variable names with a leading lowercase letter, it's possible.

```
public var thing : Thing = Thing()
```

Comment: oh, well in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the following doesn't work:

```
public var thing: Thing = Thing()
```

There error is likely in the init method of Thing

Comment: The init method doesn't do anything.